font-variation-settings aren't applying in @font-face
I'm trying to add Google's Material Symbols Outlined to a set of pages that all share the same CSS file. Some of the icons on these pages are being added using the material-symbols-outlined class, and others are being added through CSS using pseudo-classes. I'd like to have all of the material symbols be filled in, not just the ones that are added through the material-symbols-outlined class.
To try to accomplish this, I added font-variation-settings to the end of the @font-face below.
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url(../fonts/MaterialSymbolsOutlined.woff2) format('woff');
    font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 1;
  }

  .material-symbols-outlined {
    font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
  }

However, material symbols on my pages are still showing up not filled in. When I apply the same font-variation-settings to the .material-symbols-outlined class, it fills in the icons for icons added with that class, but not for icons added with pseudo-classes. How can I apply the fill property to any element that has a font-family of Material Symbols Outlined?

You can't define feature setiings or styles in the @font-face rule. These belong to the style rule. Besides you @font-face has a syntax error: it must be format(woff2) wrong format identifiers can break the complet rule.

@herrstrietzel that's not entirely correct - font-variation-settings is supported in font-face in the spec, it's just that no browser other than Firefox has supported it so far: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_font-face_font-variation-settings

@6twenty: Thanks a lot for the clarification! You're right CSS font module Level 4 supports setting a font-variation within @font-face . However, specifying a font-variation in @font-face (apart from the lacking support in 2024) won't serve as a global style rule just as any other font-face rules are intended to map specific font properties to font files. These new options are handy to create named instances or map certain variations to the same font-family name while switching the actual font-file reference (and probably a lot more use cases).
